# A too long link life for S3 object Boto3

Tags: url, amazon-s3, boto, ceph

After i've generated link on s3 object with boto3, it is living to long...
Too many then it's writen.

```
        url = client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': bucket_id,
                'Key': key
            },
            ExpiresIn=linc_exp_time
        )
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? Are you saying that the Presigned URL is valid for longer than you want? What is the value of `linc_exp_time`?

Comment: Sorry, **linc_exp_time** is my variable. when i setting linc_exp_time=100, link should be valid for 100 seconds, right? But it valid for 10, 15, 25 minutes...

Comment: Is your object publicly accessible, without a pre-signed URL? That is, can you access it via a normal (non-presigned) link?

Comment: No, with without a pre-signed URL my object is not accessible.

Comment: Also in three experiments i had not the same results: 3 second link die after 3 sec, 10 seconds link die after 10 sec, 60 second link not die after 60 sec...

Comment: Your browser might be caching the results. You can test it in a different browser, or by using `wget` or `curl` to download rather than using a browser.

Comment: thank you. You are right. Everything work with 'wget'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser might be caching the results. You can test it in a different browser, or by using wget or curl to download rather than using a browser. -- [***John Rotenstein***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein)